# Transform data in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Say I m having this large database with different kind of data, like 567, 6788, 456 mixed with other type of data like:45.67; 78.78; etc. I am trying to transform all the values that doesn't has a point in between, like 567 in 56.7, 6788 in 67.88 etc. I tried a method: spliting the data into two column and afterwards, use concat formula in excel, but it doesn't keep the leading zero if it encounters one. Does someone knows a formula do to it automatically, as my database is very large? thank you

Comment: You might wanna show us some sample data (text, image) of before and after the transformation incl. the problematic case, and maybe the formulas you used. You can improve your question by clicking the edit button below your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
'45.67   --->    45.67
'78.78   --->    78.78
'567     --->    56.7
'6788    --->    67.88

Option Explicit
Public Function add_dot(actRange As Range) As String
    If actRange.Value Like "*.*" Then
        add_dot = actRange.Value
    Else
        add_dot = Left(actRange.Value, 2) & "." & Mid(actRange.Value, 2) ', Len(actRange.Value) - 2)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

In VBA you could use regex to do this -> Use regex expression: "(\d+)"

Here's a function that can be used for this.

```
Public Function RegexExtractAll(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional separator As String = "") As String()

    ' This function takes a text, a regex expression and an optional separator character (default is "").
    ' It uses vbscript.regexp to delivers all matches and sub matches of the regex as a string array.

    Dim allMatches As Variant
    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim result() As String

    RE.Pattern = extract_what
    RE.Global = True

    On Error Resume Next
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

    If Not (IsEmpty(allMatches) Or (allMatches.Count = 0)) Then

        ReDim result(allMatches.Count - 1)

        For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Count - 1
                result(i) = result(i) & (separator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j))
            Next
        Next

    End If

    RegexExtractAll = result

End Function 'RegexExtractAll
```

To test that it works:

```
Sub SomeTest()

    ' The RegexExtractAll will return an array with the matches.
    ' By using Join() we merge them to one string.
    Debug.Print Join(RegexExtractAll("655.44,32", "(\d+)"), "")

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, you'll need to add reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" (in VBA IDE: Tools > References...)